# Handle data filtering with Eloquent and Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've got a table which returns a large set of data from the database, but I was curious about the way that most people are filter the data.

So for example I got a table with type, name, date.
In this table I want to filter where type = "New" in a descending order.

How would you accomplish this in the url and in the code?

Something like `url?type=new&sort=-type`?

Cause personally I dont like this format.. Trying to find a way to keep the url nice and clean.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
$data = Model::whereType(Input::get('type'))->orderBy(Input::get('sort'),'DESC')->get();
```

but it won't work if someone pass as `sort` not column name, so you should filter it first and then pass to Eloquent, for example:

```
$sort = Input::get('sort');

$allowed = ['name','active','someothercolumn'];

if (!in_array($sort, $allowed)) {
  $sort = $allowed[0];
}

$data = Model::whereType(Input::get('type'))->orderBy($sort,'DESC')->get();
```